# Is zero-byte file a valid sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite

When I call sqlite3_open_v2() on a zero byte file with flag SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, the function returns zero. Then the "PRAGMA quick_check;" statement returns a row containing string "ok". So zero-byte file is considered a valid database? Seems a little counter-intuitive?

Comment: Could be one with no schema, tables, or data.

Comment: (this is obscure and may help no one, but...) i was opening a zero-byte file but then seeing "unable to open database file" when running a CREATE TABLE statement. it turned out that sqlite had permission to use the zero-byte file, but sqlite was unable to create its necessary supporting temp files due to permissions lock-down in that directory. https://sqlite.org/tempfiles.html

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't think it's "valid". If it's zero bytes, it's nothing, other than a reference. Yes you can open it. But that's not working if the file has >= 1 byte.

So as long as the file is 0 bytes, you can open it; once you start making changes, it will become an SQLite file.

If you open a non-SQLite file and try to make changes, it will give you an error message:

> Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

Answer (score -1):

The (only) way to create a new, empty database is to attempt to open a non-existing file.
A zero-sized file is considered the same; it's just an empty database.

There are some settings (such as the [page size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size)) that must be set inside an opened database connection, but that would affect the structure of the database file.
Therefore, SQLite delays actually writing the database structure until it is actually needed.

Comment: I don't think thats true. If i touch a file (linux), i can then still open this file with sqllite and start creating tables. Provided the file is empty.

Comment: How does this contradict what I wrote?

Comment: You write a **non** existing file. A zero byte file, is still a file. As long is 0, it should still work.